# getCount of a specific pattern in a string using code points in java

Tags: java

`public static int getCount(String string1, String pattern1)`

I want to find the count of the pattern in string1 using code points and not regex. For instance,  the string is 'abd555c' and the pattern1 is '55'. So the output should be 2 using code points. How would i implement this method?

Comment: please explain a bit For instance, the string is 'abd555c' and the pattern1 is '55'. So the output should be 2 using code points.

Comment: This method follows the same idea as regex but we use code points instead. We check the number of times the pattern appears in the string. Example, the input parameters are string1 = "abc" and pattern1 ="a" so the number of times 'a' appears in the original string is 1.

Comment: so how come count for '55' in 'abd555c' is 2?

Comment: when going through a loop, the first time it takes into account the first 2 5's. Then the second time it takes into account the 2nd and 3rd 5.  It's like abd55, then 55c.

Comment: Please mind to post your attempt then you can seek for improvements

Answer (score 0):

I have a tricky solution, you can optimize it based on your requirement.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string1="abd555c";
    String pattern1="55";


    while(string1.contains(pattern1)) {
        string1=string1.replace("55","__5");
    }
    String ab[]=string1.split("__");
    System.out.println(ab.length-1);

}
```